# How can I put a single Quote in a string without the backslash in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to format the data of my table with a number format like this:
`wsOptimisation.ListObjects("tblOptiData").DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = "#'##0.0 ""mm"""`
If I run this Code it pastes it like this:
`#\'##0.0 "mm"`
VBA adds the backslash and thus it won't get recognized as the 1000 seperator.

Edit:
I changed the 1000 seperator from , to '

How can I get rid of the backslash?

Image from Format Cells Window in Excel:
[excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LP4cI.png)

I tried using the Chr(39) function, but same issue.

Comment: Use a comma if you want the thousands separator, or use `NumberFormatLocal`

Comment: I changed the 1000 seperator to ' but using the NumberFormatLocal worked. Thank you!